# How does recoil affect movement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

What happens if you shoot a canon inside a car? What are the forces involved in this process? If you shoot a canon in the back of a truck, would the vehicle move backwards in the time span from when the bullet leaves the canon and when it hits the opposite wall?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking about a closed truck:

Just before the cannon is fired, the truck, cannon, cannon-ball and gunpowder are all at rest, with velocity and total momentum equal to zero.

(This applies even to moving trucks;  just use the moving truck, before firing, as your frame of reference)

Once the cannon is fired, the cannon-ball *and the gunpowder, converted to gases and fine particles*, are all travelling in one direction, with a considerable momentum. Since the force of the explosion is an internal one to the truck-cannon-cannonball system, the total momentum must remain at zero, so some other part of the system must have an exactly opposite momentum.

If the cannon is just lying in the truck, it (the cannon) will recoil.  If the cannon is firmly attached to the truck, the cannon and truck will recoil.

When the cannon-ball and the gases hit the wall of the truck, they will stop, and will, at the same time, cancel out the recoil velocity of the truck.

The net effect, after all the dust settles, will be that the truck, cannon, cannonball and gases will be at rest.  The truck will have moved one way slightly, and the cannonball will have moved the other way.

If the truck were carefully balanced on a knife-edge before firing, and held in place during the firing, it will still be balanced, after the firing. (Assuming that the truck is airtight, and contains all the gas produced by the propellant...)